# Home page only page accessible, no login with clean urls

Tags: migrations, .htaccess, acquia-dev-desktop

I'm trying to copy a live site to my windows development machine for some module testing and updates. I have a copy of the complete live site's codebase (entire drupal root from live server) and the the sql dump file for the live site.

I'm using Acquia's Dev Desktop, and I use the import local site option, point the installer to the correct files and sql dump. The issue is that the installation seems to fail, in that navigating to the site triggers the installation script, and my database name and settings are imported but the database itself is empty. I then imported the correct database manually and ran the update.php script, but then only my home page shows up. Any page that isn't the home page gives me a 404 error, and I can't use clean urls to login, `?q=user/login` also gets me a 404.

I've checked the .htaccess file and it exists.

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the catch-all handler to prevent scripts from being executed.
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
<Files *>
  # Override the handler again if we're run later in the evaluation list.
  SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2013_003
</Files>

# If we know how to do it safely, disable the PHP engine entirely.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
```

I don't think it would have to with my Apache settings because, that should all be taken care of by Acquia installer.

Where on the computer should the codebase folder be placed?

Is there anything special to how I should be copying the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Acquia Dev Desktop configured Apache correctly, then you're most likely missing your .htaccess file in the ***root*** of your Drupal install.

I know sometimes on Windows machines **.htaccess** is hidden within FTP clients, and you need to change a setting so that  you can see the file in directory listings.

The content of your .htaccess file you posted is from the Drupal **files directory**, which is usually located within **/sites/default/files**

Double check that you **.htaccess** exists in the route, and that it has the correct contents. I'd recommend grabbing an original copy from Drupal core.

Comment: no problem, glad I could help.